# SCP fails almost immediately with 'lost connection' after successful ssh connection

Tags: shell, ssh, sh, scp

I am writing a script to upload DLLs to a remote machine. I first use a command to `ssh` in and stop the service running. I then try to upload the new DLLs via `scp`, but it fails basically immediately with `lost connection`.

My entire shell script looks like this:

```
ssh -p 29170 DLL_Uploader@XXX.XXX.XX.XXX "powershell.exe; .\stop_file_watcher.ps1; exit";
scp -P 29170 $1 "DLL_Uploader@XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:/Bin/File Watcher Service"
ssh -p 29170 DLL_Uploader@XXX.XXX.XX.XXX "powershell.exe; .\start_file_watcher.ps1; exit";
```

You can see a pastebin of this `scp` debug output with `-vvv` [here](https://pastebin.com/AjxRn49Q).

Comment: Note that if your local filename has spaces in it, `$1` needs to be `"$1"`. Really, you should do that unconditionally out of habit; the places where there's a reason to not quote expansion of a string-type variable are places one ought to use an array (and quote its expansion) instead.

Comment: If you change your scp command to write to a different filename that doesn't have anything preexisting, does it succeed? (This is guesswork, though -- the place to investigate is the server side, not the client, if you want a sound understanding of what's going on)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If I target the directory above, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Sorry? If it works perfectly fine, why are you asking a question here?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy By "directory above," I mean the parent directory of the one I'm trying to upload to. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: One place to look is directory permissions. Another is whether it's replacing an existing file that's the problem, rather than the directory the file is in. Another is whether the spaces in the names cause problems (they wouldn't if scp were behaving its usual way, but your server being on Windows, it's probably not reasonable to expect things to behave the usual way).

Comment: (on UNIXy systems, one can replace an in-use executable or shared library without it being a problem as long as one is putting a reference to a new inode under the old name, as opposed to rewriting the blocks associated with an old inode; but while modern enough versions of NTFS _can_ support that mode of operation, my understanding is that the stock syscalls don't, for better compatibility with older Windows releases).